# How to use environment variables set in Terraform Cloud?

Tags: terraform, github-actions

I am using Terraform to integrate with GitHub Actions and AWS.

I want Terraform to setup `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` in GitHub repository secrets for GitHub Actions using the environment variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` that I've set in Terraform Cloud.

[image: Screenshot of Terraform Cloud Environment Variables configuration]

I want to write something like below.

```
resource "github_actions_secret" "example_secret" {
  repository      = "example_repository"
  secret_name     = "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
  plaintext_value = env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY // <-- this will not work
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Terraform Cloud will [automatically export any environment variables](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cloud/workspaces/variables.html#environment-variables) to populate your shell environment before running any Terraform.

This is equivalent to running [`export TF_VAR_foo=bar`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/config/environment-variables.html#tf_var_name) if you wanted to set `foo` to `bar`.

To then actually use these variables you must define a variable block as normal and then access it as usual as well.

So in your case if you have defined an `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` environment variable in Terraform Cloud then you could do this:

```
variable "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" {}

resource "github_actions_secret" "example_secret" {
  repository      = "example_repository"
  secret_name     = "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
  plaintext_value = var.aws_secret_access_key
}
```

Comment: Seems not working in my case. By the way, I defined the environment value in the terraform cloud. And it reported the error: `The root module input variable "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" is not set, and has no
│ default value. Use a -var or -var-file command line argument to provide a
│ value for this variable.`.

Comment: You need to define the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` variable as per the first line in my example. I left that one off because your example didn't use it and only referenced the `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`